# Best way to design a URI for REST API

Tags: rest, api, uri, url-design

I am designing a REST API with similar functionality as of Posts and Comments in Facebook.

URI looks like:

```
/posts/{post-id}/comments/{comment-id}
```

To get all the comments I use the collection URI naming standard. For example:

```
/posts/{post-id}/comments
```

But I am having difficulty when I need comments for all the posts. What would be the best way to incorporate that keeping in mind that I want to use this design only for posts and comments?

#### Edit

I have to mention here that the resources I am using are a bit different from posts and comments in a way that the in my design I will have to use posts and cannot have comments as entirely different entity. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Said that, is it recommended to design URI in any of these ways:

```
/posts//comments

/posts/"any-string"/comments
```

Answer (score 0):

> But i am having difficulty when i need comments for all the posts. What would be the best way to incorporate that keeping in mind that i want to use this design only for posts and comments.

HTTP includes the concept of [redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) - a general facility for telling the client to send a request to some other resource.

```
GET /714eeebd-d89e-4f13-b2a8-cf8a3ee03481 ...

307 Temporary Redirect
Location: /7604abf9-d4f5-42c7-b687-96dbff32649f
```

What this *means* is that, if you choose the wrong spelling for your URI, you can correct it later.

The design of REST is such that identifiers are opaque - nobody other than the server is supposed to be extracting information from them.

Also, keep in mind that resources are not domain entities -- it's normal to have many more *resources* than you have domain objects.  Any given Post in your domain model might have many different resources that show it.

If you are really developing a REST service, and you want to "help" clients by making it difficult to cheat, you may want to abandon the idea of using a [hackable identifier](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/05/01/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-hackable-urls/).

All that said

```
/comments
```

is a perfectly reasonable collection identifier all on its own, and its perfectly reasonable to create an identifier hierarchy under that root.

Answer (score 0):

Below URI should serve the purpose.

> **/comments**

For the above given example, let's understand the relationship of entities and URI:

**posts** and **comments** are two entities on its own.

when you need only posts and just passing post_id

> To retrieve the posts:
>
> ```
> /posts
> ```
>
> To retrieve a specific post:
>
> ```
> /posts/{post_id}
> ```

when you need only comments and just passing comment_id

> To retrieve all comments:
>
> ```
> /comments
> ```
>
> To retrieve specific comment:
>
> ```
> /comments/{comment_id}
> ```

when you need comments for a given post by passing both post_id and comment_id

> To retrieve comments on a post:
>
> ```
> /posts/{post_id}/comments
> ```
>
> To retrieve specific comment for given post:
>
> ```
> /posts/{post_id}/comments/{comment_id}
> ```

Hope it solves your issue.